Approximation of Kalman Gain
I am reading this lecture note
https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/2-160-identification-estimation-and-learning-spring-2006/825d8851ab6950cebfab991c3e435f90_lecture_7.pdf
I'm wondering why is below approximation true? Is there a similar form in discrete kalman filter?


Perhaps $\left( {\Delta t \cdot H_t P_{t|t - 1} H_t^T  + R} \right)^{ - 1}  = R^{ - 1} \left( {\Delta t \cdot H_t P_{t|t - 1} H_t^T R^{ - 1}  + I} \right)^{ - 1}  \cong R^{ - 1} $, since $\Delta t \cdot H_t P_{t|t - 1} H_t^T R^{ - 1}  + I \cong I$ if $|\Delta t| \ll 1$.

There is, but I don't see it as being useful.  In the standard discrete-time Kalman formulation, if you define
$$P_k^- = F_{k-1}P_{k-1}^+F_{k-1}^T + Q_{k-1} \tag 1$$
then
$$\begin{align}
K_k &= P_k^-H_k^T \left (H_k P_k^-H_k^T + R_k \right)^{-1} \tag 2 \\
    &= P_k^+H_k^TR_k^{-1} \tag 3
\end{align}$$
So, yes, (3) is present, but I don't know if there's a way to make use of it.
